# spark streaming and kafka, increase the number of messages that spark pulles from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have an application that produces 60,000 messages per second.
I send messages to the Kafka and I want to receive those messages by spark streaming in other application, 
but the rate of messages that Spark receives is ~ 40,000. I want to increase the number of messages that Spark receives per interval, how can I do that ?

Comment: what param do you use for spark-submit?

Comment: I do not set any configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In kafka, the degree of parallelism is determined by the number of partitions of the topic.

You need to increase the number of partitions in the topic.

And you need to set the number of executers that run spark streaming to match the number of partitions in kafka as much as possible.

This will give you optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing **spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition**.
You can try this equation **(spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition)* (your partitions) = 60000**.
But would suggest to keep spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition a little higher just in case of spikes in incoming messages.